# python NumPy Value Error Issue

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and am unsure as to how to fix the following error using NumPy:

```
if (energy < min_energy):
    min_energy = energy;
    min_pos_current = c;
    min_pos_previous = p;

if (energy < min_energy):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can someone assist me this issue?

Comment: Don't understand exactly what's your problem.

Comment: How do `energy` and `min_energy` get their values prior to the `if` statement?

Comment: Looks like numpy error to me.

Comment: You can't compare oranges and apples.

Comment: The program works on another image but not for the one specified. In theory, it should work!?

Comment: @CarnezDavis How could anyone even dare to guess whether it should work or not, if we don't know what `energy` and `min_energy` are...

Comment: You need to make your post clearer. We can't guess this came from num_py.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Well, anyone who uses NumPy can guess that it comes from NumPy. But that still means this question is wasting the time of (and possibly encouraging useless comments or incorrect answers from) the 80% or more of Python developers who'd like to help but have never even heard of NumPy, so your point is still 100% valid.

Comment: Should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

This error comes from NumPy.

In NumPy, when you compare two arrays with `<`, you get an array, the result of an element-wide comparison—exactly the same as when you add two arrays with `+`:

Look at this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 2, 2])
>>> a+b
array([3, 4, 5])
>>> a < b
array([True, False, False])
```

So, what is `if` to do with that `array([True, False, False])`? It's not true, it's not false; it's a collection of values, some true, some false. Which is why NumPy gives you an error message that says exactly that: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

You have to decide what you're actually trying to test here. Whatever you might want, there's probably an easy way to write it—for example, if you want to know whether all of the values of `a` are less than the corresponding values of `b`, that's `(a < b).all()`. But that obviously doesn't work if you want to compare, e.g., the norms of `a` and `b` treated as vectors. Or if you want to lexicographically compare them as if they were Python tuples. And so on. Without knowing which of the limitless possible meanings you might want here, nobody can tell you how to write it.

Comment: So, should it be:
 (energy < min_energy).all():
    min_energy = energy
    min_pos_current = c
    min_pos_previous = p

Comment: @CarnezDavis: I don't know. Is that what you actually want to test, or not? Again, there are limitless possible things that might make sense, and without knowing anything about what you're trying to do, I have no idea which one you actually mean.